# Interactive Surveys (Theranos) - PATENT APPLICATION - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, theranos, us20140095189, surveys

The following application was filed in 2013 and directed to interactive surveys where a picture is shown based on the inputted information.

It seems that companies have been providing this for a number of years now - for example, http://www.snapsurveys.com/survey-software/sample-surveys/  Wayback has the page existing prior to the filing date of this application.

The Application in question is:

Publication number  US20140095189 A1
Application number  US 14/035,762

Publication date    Apr 3, 2014
Filing date         **Sep 24, 2013**

A representative claim -

(a) presenting, with the aid of a computer system and an interactive display operatively coupled to the computer system, a query to a user, said query relating to said user's dietary consumption, exercise, health condition or mental condition;

(b) receiving, with the aid of said computer system and interactive display, a response to said query from said user; and

(c) interpreting, with the aid of a computer processor, said response based on a set of reference information, wherein said set of reference information comprises a pictorial depiction of portion size of said dietary consumption, exertion level of said exercise, existing state of said health condition or existing state of said mental condition.

Can anyone find better prior art than snapsurveys?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this qualifies as prior art, but there is an app "MealSnap" that takes a picture of food and gives you calories and such information about the food. It looks realitvly knew so may not qualify.

It also sounds like some of this conflicts with Google's image search. Which allows you to upload an image(query) and recieve search results of that image. (In my opion this conflicts with "said response based on a set of reference information, wherein ...")

http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html

Answer (score 1):

This link (dated 2012 from archive.org) might be useful: https://web.archive.org/web/20120827014645/http://www.eatthismuch.com/?

This also looks very similar: https://web.archive.org/web/20120210130034/http://www.webmd.com/diet/food-fitness-planner/default.htm

Answer (score 1):

Every app in [this list of Diet Tracking Apps](http://mashable.com/2012/08/25/diet-tracking-apps/) does what is described in the patent

The list was published in August 2013